# Using VerticalAlignment with InlineGraphicElement inside TextFlow AS3 Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am making a paragraph of text using a number of `SpanElements` within a `ParagraphElement`, all inside a `TextFlow`. It also has a number of `InlineGaphicElements`, some of which have a height greater than the text line height. In these cases I'd like the graphic to be positioned so that the text aligns with the middle of the image.

The most obvious thing I've found that would seem to do this is setting the `VerticalAlignment` property within the `InlineGaphicElement`s to `VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE`, but these seems to make no difference, no matter what I set it to. I think this is because it can only be applied to an entire `TextFlow` inside a container.

I'm hitting a bit of a wall with this so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately TLF is not so OPEN when it comes to composition algorithm even if it is open-source. I suggest you update the InlineGraphicElement and play with the graphic (your actual Image) and see if you can add some paddings in there in order to get the desired look. I know this is more like a hack than a solution but that is all I can came with now.

Answer (score 0):

Set InlineGaphicElements baselineShift.